# Finding/determining future data for pricing

Tags: design, c#, sql, sql-server, .net-core

I'm honestly not even sure how to go about how to ask what I'm looking for/need. lol.

I'm currently using `Sql Server` for my database and the '*new*' `.net 5`. There are multiple pricing tables that each have their own purpose for pricing lineitems on an order. These pricings get updated quite often, ranging from either monthly to once a year.

In the system they're currently using(super old), when a new pricing system comes out they create an entirely new table with those values, everytime. They do this because when an order is placed, it needs to get what the price would be on it's due date.

**For example:**

> 'orderA' is placed December 20th with a due date of December 30th. 'orderA' uses the current pricing data that's in effect.

> 'orderB' is placed on the same day, December 20th, but it has a due date of Jan 1st. 'orderB' would use the future data for pricing.

The example above is why they currently just create an entirely new table every time any pricing gets updated. I obviously do not want to do that, for a multitude of reasons.

I currently have functionality in place where users can schedule updates to different tables. This is basically just a `stored procedure` that creates a `Sql Agent Job` that gets triggered to execute an update query on a specific date.

Now this handles the ability to schedule updates, but it does not handle the ability to view if or what future data may be, which is the problem I'm running into.

I've looked into `time-series data` a bit, but I'm not entirely sure if that's the best course of action.

I'm also not entirely sure what kind of information can be pulled from a specific scheduled job.
I feel that if I am able to get the jobs command, I'd need to essentially execute that query against current data without actually updating it to get the future data values **or** parse the query into a usable format I can use. Plus doing this, would probably cause big performance issues as it'd need to get ran multiple times for each line item in an order, depending on various pricing conditions.

So, what is the best course of action I should take? Whether it's something I have mentioned or there's something I haven't mentioned, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need scheduled jobs and new tables. Just have one table

```
Price
    ItemId    // cokecola
    DateFrom  // 2001-01-01 00:00:00
    DateTo    // 2010-01-01 00:00:00
    Price     // 150
```

Then select the price which is valid for your target date

```
select * from price
where itemId = @id
and DateFrom < @targetDate
and (
   DateTo is null
   or
   DateTo >= @targetDate
)
```

Now I've put two dates in there to make it easy to understand. But actually you can just use a single DateFrom and adjust your select to get the row with the min DateFrom which is still less than your target.

When you want to update prices, you just add new rows.

Comment: I did forget to edit in that I have considered just adding a timestamp column and forcing users to enter in a new row for every single pricing table/row. But since our pricing system is super convoluted(based on custom algorithms), I was really hoping to avoid that as that will be very time consuming for the end-user.

Comment: why would they be forced to enter any more data than they are currently?

Comment: Because if I were to enforce a start/end date on all our pricing tables, that would mean forcing users to enter in a lot of duplicate data every month/bi-monthly/yearly/etc... Which is a lot of redundancy and horrible UX. All of which is dependent on the specific pricing table.

Comment: what do they enter now?

Comment: there's no extra data here so you shoul dbe able to take whatever they enter now and write code to do the equivalent operation. ie "next month everything is 10% more" just insert into price (select the current prices *1.1, nextmonthsdate)

Comment: Currently, in the software they select a specific price row that will be updated. Change a single value and select when they want the update to go into effect. Which that called the stored proc I mentioned in the post. I suppose, I could just say screw redundancy and make a system where they basically 'clone' a selected record, and in the background set the 'old' record enddate a day before the new records startdate and have the single change value. The current system I have in place has essentially zero redundancy and I was hoping I could do the same.

Comment: if you switch to the single date method you can just insert and not worry abouty updating the old row

Comment: Yep, I guess the main point of this entire post was me looking to see if there was a way I could help keep redundancy at a minimum in the database. I feared that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: tbh the current way sounds the same as the labour intensive way you worry about, they have to enter a price and a date for every item?

Comment: The current way isn't as labor intensive as what I'm planning to do now. I should be able to get it almost as 'quick' as before. Me asking this question was a combination of me overthinking what needs to be done and wanting to reduce the amount of DB records that are identical except a single column value (besides the startdate columns I'm gonna be adding).